# IronPython XNA Eclipse/PyDev "SystemError: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly."

Tags: .net, xna, pydev, ironpython

Thanks in advance for any/all help/insight and for taking the time to read this.

When trying to run the below program, I am getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\dt85738\Documents\python\IronPythonTest\Test.py", line 88, in
>
> File "C:\Users\dt85738\Documents\python\IronPythonTest\Test.py", line 34, in **init**
>
> File "C:\Users\dt85738\Documents\python\IronPythonTest\Test.py", line 37, in initializeComponent
>
> SystemError: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.

I am able to run the C# equivalent to this in Visual Studio.
I have compiled a C# wrapper around GraphicsDeviceManager and gotten the same error when using it via IronPython.
I have tried calling GraphicsDeviceManager(self) hundreds of times rapidly, never successfully loading it up.

I am using:

XNA 4.0

IronPython 2.7.4

PyDev

My complete program:

```
import clr
  
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Avatar.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.AudioImporters.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.EffectImporter.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.FBXImporter.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.TextureImporter.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.VideoImporters.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.XImporter.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video.dll")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact.dll")

from Microsoft.Xna.Framework import GraphicsDeviceManager
from Microsoft.Xna.Framework import Game
from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content import ContentManager
from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics import Texture2D
from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics import SpriteBatch
from Microsoft.Xna.Framework import Color
from Microsoft.Xna.Framework import Rectangle

class MyGame(Game):
    def __init__(self):
        self.spriteX = self.spriteY = 0
        self.spriteSpeedX = self.spriteSpeedY = 1
        self.initializeComponent()

    def initializeComponent(self):
        self.graphics = GraphicsDeviceManager(self)#this is line 37 (where it breaks)
        self.content = ContentManager(self.Services)

    def LoadGraphicsContent(self, loadAllContent):
        if loadAllContent:
            self.texture = Texture2D.FromFile(self.graphics.GraphicsDevice, "sprite.jpg")
            self.spriteBatch = SpriteBatch(self.graphics.GraphicsDevice)
           
    def UnloadGraphicsContent(self, unloadAllContent):
        if unloadAllContent:
            self.texture.Dispose()
            self.spritebatch.Dispose()

    def Update(self, gameTime):
        self.UpdateSprite()
       
        Game.Update(self, gameTime)

    def UpdateSprite(self):       
        self.spriteX += self.spriteSpeedX
        self.spriteY += self.spriteSpeedY

        maxX = self.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - self.texture.Width
        if self.spriteX > maxX:
            self.spriteSpeedX *= -1
            self.spriteX = maxX
        elif self.spriteX < 0:
            self.spriteSpeedX *= -1
            self.spriteX = 0

        maxY = self.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - self.texture.Height
        if self.spriteY > maxY:
            self.spriteSpeedY *= -1
            self.spriteX = maxY
        elif self.spriteY < 0:
            self.spriteSpeedY *= -1
            self.spriteY = 0

    def Draw(self, gameTime):
        self.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue)
       
        self.DrawSprite()
       
        Game.Draw(self, gameTime)
       
    def DrawSprite(self):
        self.spriteBatch.Begin()
        self.spriteBatch.Draw(self.texture, Rectangle(self.spriteX, self.spriteY, self.texture.Width, self.texture.Height), Color.White)
        self.spriteBatch.End()


game = MyGame()
game.Run()
```

Error After adding -X:ExceptionDetail -X:ShowClrExceptions to the command line:

The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.

GetManifestResourceStream at offset 56 in file:line:column :0:0

ReadDefaultGraphicsProfile at offset 59 in file:line:column :0:0

.ctor at offset 345 in file:line:column :0:0

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.NewInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)

at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)

at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke1Instruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

at IronPython.Compiler.PythonCallTargets.OriginalCallTarget1(PythonFunction function, Object arg0)

at IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCaller`1.Call1(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object func, T0 arg0)

at IronPython.Runtime.Method.MethodBinding.SelfTarget(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object target)

at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

at IronPython.Runtime.Types.PythonType.FastTypeSite.CallTarget(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object type)

at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke0Instruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

at IronPython.Compiler.PythonCallTargets.OriginalCallTarget1(PythonFunction function, Object arg0)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)

at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)

at IronPython.Runtime.Types.LateBoundInitBinder.FastInitSite.CallTarget(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object inst)

at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

at IronPython.Runtime.Types.PythonType.FastTypeSite.CallTarget(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object type)

at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

at IronPython.Runtime.FunctionCaller.Call0(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object func)

at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke0Instruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)

at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)

at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)

at IronPython.Hosting.PythonCommandLine.RunFileWorker(String fileName)

at IronPython.Hosting.PythonCommandLine.RunFile(String fileName)

SystemError: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.

CLR Exception:

```
NotSupportedException
```

:

The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.

Comment: Can you add `-X:ExceptionDetail -X:ShowClrExceptions` to the command line and post the result? that should help show where the error is coming from exactly.

Comment: Added the full error after adding "-X:ExceptionDetail -X:ShowClrExceptions" above.